# XmlSerializer serializes 0-bytes document or sometimes nothing

Tags: c#, uwp

I have this giving me problems:

```
StorageFile settings = await GetSettingsFile();
Stream stream = await settings.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Setting>));
serializer.Serialize(stream, SettingsList);
stream.Flush();
stream.Dispose();
```

Sometimes this works fine, sometimes this truncates the file to 0 bytes, and sometimes it writes nothing.

This snippet is being called in the destructive phase of the application, in the `Suspending` event, to save a list of `Setting` objects to a XML file. The `Settings` object is a simple object with 2 properties, a `key` and a `value`.

Why is this misbehaving?

Comment: Do you take a deferral on the suspension event?

Comment: Can you provide more details? I just call the above method at the end of the suspension event.

Comment: If you perform a web search for "UWP suspend deferral" you should get some details. You can also press `F1` within Visual Studio to get help on any type, property, method, or event.